# Probability distribution of a moving particle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, physics, word-problem

I am having a issue with the wording of this question.

> Find the probability of the following.
>
> The velocity $v$ of a randomly selected particle, whose distribution obeys the probability density function
>
> $$P(\frac{v}{v_{avg}})=exp(-\frac{v}{v_{avg}})$$
> will lie between 0 and $2_{v_{avg}}$ where $v_{avg}$ is the average velocity.

I have been given the density function so I just integrated between the limits to find the probability between the given points.

which came to be $P(0\leq v \leq 2v_{avg})=0.86 v_{avg}$

However I am not happy with this as to me the probability can change given a different average velocity which dose not make sense.

I have looked at various probability distribution information in a text book am I using by John E.Frenuds and I cant see to find anything that jumps out then only thing that did is the use of 'probability density' where they define a given function
say

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
kx^2 >0 \\0  \: everywhere \: else
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So then it get normalized and integrated between given limits, which make me think the above equation given is maybe a 'probability density function' as been used in the book.

Could someone maybe explain if I have use the correct method and if not, expand where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Note that the probability density you're given is the probability density of a variable $v/v_{avg}$, not just $v$. So you need to calculate $P(0<v/v_{avg}<2) = \int_0^2 e^{-x} dx$.

Comment: Please notice that your distribution P() is not a probability distribution function (PDF) of $v$ as it is not normalized. The PDF is rather $f(v)=\frac{1}{v_{avg}} Exp\left(- \frac{v}{v_{avg}}\right)$. The average of $v$ is then $<v> = \int_0^\infty v f(v) \,dv = v_{avg}$, the variance is $<(v-v_{avg})^2>= v_{avg}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your calculation is correct, but the result itself requires the normalization factor $a=v_{avg}$, since 
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t}{a}}\;dt = a$$

The probability is then independent of the average velocity because of the specific properties of the exponential distribution:

You have in general 
$$\frac {1}{a}\int_0^{2a}e^{-\frac{t}{a}}\;dt= \int_0^{2}e^{-x}\;dx = 1-\frac{1}{e^2}$$

With other probability distributions you may not see such a result in general.

Comment: In general $e^{-t/a}$ isn't a probability density, because it's not normalized. And if you do normalize it, the dependence of the final result on $a$ vanishes.

Comment: Totally right. I oversaw this missing factor.  will adjust correspondingly. Thank you.

Comment: @james2018 : I had to adjust the answer as the distribution in you question seems to miss a normalization factor depending on how one interprets it. If the  distribution refers to $v$, then the distribution needs normalization. If it refers to $v/v_{avg}$, then all is good but integration limits need to be from 0 to 2.